# DISTINCT function is not working in my SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner in SQL and am working on this project. It's asking me to pull a distinct list of clients (ClientID) that have ever made an purchase, sorted by ClientID ascending.

I seem to have everything right except for the fact that my results aren't distinct, I am still getting duplicates in the ClientID. What could I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ClientID, ClientName, o.PurchaseID   

FROM Purchases o JOIN Clients c   

ON o.ClientID = c.ClientID 

ORDER BY c.ClientID ASC;
```

Comment: please show input sample and expected output

Comment: I suspect your OrderId is not distinct, Removing the OrderId from select statement may solve your problem.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is for the whole row. So if you include the order-id in your results, of course customers who placed more than one order will show up multiple times

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, CustomerName, o.OrderID
```

This means you select distinct combination of CustomerID, CustomerName and OrderID.
Due to you need dicticnt CustomerID, you can write like bellowing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName

FROM Orders o JOIN Customers c   

ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 

ORDER BY c.CustomerID ASC
```

Comment: I just tried this code to see where it'd take me, and it keeps telling me that the column o.CustomerName doesn't exist, but it does (within the Customers table). I have had this issue with a few other problems. Do you know why SQL says a column doesn't exist when it does?

Comment: maybe the CustomerName is in table Customers, the code should be ``` SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName

FROM Orders o JOIN Customers c   

ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 

ORDER BY c.CustomerID ASC```     I have updated my answer.

Comment: Because there is an error in the query and it should be `c.Customername`. `o` references to the `orders` table

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the distinct list of customers who has made an order, you should be able to select it from the Orders tables itself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
FROM Orders order by CustomerID
```

should be able to fetch the unique list of CustomerID's

Comment: But seems OP needs the customer name too ...